# Order and Export not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a simple java project and I reference it from an Android project. In `MainActivity` of android project I create an instance of an class which is defined in simple java project. This used to work until I physically change paths of project folders. To make sure that android project has the right project reference I deleted old project folders and re-added project reference. My code compiles. But though my java project is checked at Order and Export tab of android project, when I try running the app on a device, I still get `NoClassDefinition` exception. This exception is thrown any time android project tries to access any class defined in java project. In other words

```
Object o = AnyClassInJavaProject.class;
```

causes `NoClassDefinition` exception.

To test, I added another java project, defined class 'a.B', referenced this project from android project, checked new project from Order and Export tab, added below line to `MainActivity` code and again `NoClassDefinition` exception.

```
new a.B();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because 'Compiler compliance level' of java project. It was `1.7` and making it `1.6` solved the problem. I used to get `Unsupported Minor Major` exception for this case but for android applications it seems like unsupported versions are not included apk and causes NoClassDefinition exception.